# Name output by button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a div where the name should be displayed by pressing a button. The two buttons below, if you click on the first, the John name should appear, and if the second, Donald. Where is the mistake?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


class trueName extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    this.state = {
      name: {},
    };
  }

  john = ()=>{
    const {name}= this.state;
    this.setState({name:"John"})
  }

  donald = ()=>{
    const {name}= this.state;
    this.setState({name:"Donald"})
  }

render() {
    return(
      <div >
        <div className="SelectName">
          <span>{this.name}</span>
        </div>

        <button
        className = "one"
        onClick={ this.john}>
          <span>My name John</span>
        </button>

        <button
        className = "two"
        onClick={ this.donald}
        >
          <span>My name Donald</span>
        </button>
      </div>

    )
  }
}

export default trueName;
```

Comment: You are missing quotes here: `this.setState({name: "John"})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As other people have mentioned, you need to set the value to a string.

But also, whne you are displaying the value, you have an error. You are looking for `this.name` while what you want to display is `this.state.name`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `'`, `"` or ``` to make the value of name a string:

```
this.setState({name:'John'})
/// ...
this.setState({name:'Donald'})
```

also only constructors should be written with an uppercase letter at the beginning, not methods, rename the function `John` to `john`.